# Add millisecond value to today's date and display Date, And Month and Year (Date, Month and Year are each separate values)

Tags: javascript, date, selenium

I am trying to create a testing script in Selenium and I need to enter a date.  I have figured out how to get the dates using:
storeEval var d=new Date(); d.getDate() CurrentDay
store Eval var m=new Date(); (m.getMonth()+1) CurrentMonth
storeEval var y=new Date(); y.getFullYear() CurrentYear

Now I want want to create variables for times in the past and future. I have been told I can do so using milliseconds, which is amazing but the closest I can come is this:

storeEval new Date().getTime()+604800000 //604800000- being 7 days in the future

I get back: 1350932638018 which is 7 days forward according to this amazing [calculator](http://www.ruddwire.com/handy-code/date-to-millisecond-calculators/) I found.

So, how do I take the number I found and extract the date, month and year as I did for today's date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your future date is stored in the variable `d` then it should be as easy as:

```
var n = new Date(d);
```

or if it isn't stored in a variable, then maybe something like this?

```
var n = new Date(Date().getTime()+604800000);
```

And then now `n` is a date object and you should be able to use the `.getFullYear()` methods.

Take a look at this fiddle and see if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/wVVmw/

Comment: it throws an exception: Date().getTime is not a function :0(

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that this is a javascript answer and not a Selenium answer. But you are saying that Date.getTime() returns a number right?

Comment: yes, Date.getTime() does return a number.  Then I want to extract the Month or the year from that answer. :0)

Comment: @Orli I added a fiddle, let me know if that helps you at all!

Comment: thanks, it seems that I can return the number but everytime I try to save it as a var it throws the exception on the getTime.  I think I need to read up on my Selenium.  But thank you very much for the line, it is exactly what I wanted.. if only Selenium would like it. :0)

Answer (score 1):

use `toDateString()`

So,

```
var newDate = (Date().getTime()+604800000).toDateString();
```

should return Mon Oct 22 2012

I don't know selenium, but it looks like JavaScript.

Comment: it throws an exception: Date().getTime is not a function :0(  I'm trying to use javascript in my Selenium.. hence the multiple roadblocks.

Comment: It looks like @frshca might have it right. Date() can take a number like 1350932638018 as an argument and convert that to a date. So for example, var n = new Date(1350932638018) will be October 22, 2012